# Lagrange inversion theorem applied on $f(x)=x-x^p$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, lagrange-inversion

I was looking at the [Wikipedia page of the Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) and stumbled upon the example. It says that to find the root of the polynomial $x^p-x+z=0$ we can find the inverse of the function $f(x)=x-x^p$ using the theorem. So we have $f(x)=z$, therefore the inverse is $x=g(z)$ where
$$
g(z)=x_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g_n}{n!}(z-f(x_0))^n \qquad g_n=\lim_{w\to x_0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial w^{n-1}}\left[\left(\frac{w-x_0}{f(w)-f(x_0)}\right)^n\right]
$$
The result should be, according to Wikipedia:
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{pk}{k}\frac{z^{(p-1)k+1}}{(p-1)k+1}
$$
So, I decided to try it myself. First I put $x_0=0$, because $f'(0)=1$, and calculated $g_n$
$$
g_n=\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial w^{n-1}}\left[(1-w^{p-1})^{-n}\right]
$$
Using the negative binomial theorem we obtain
$$
g_n=\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial w^{n-1}}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}w^{-(n+k)(p-1)}\right]= \qquad |w|<1\\
=\lim_{w\to0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-(n+k)(p-1))...(-(n+k)(p-1)-n-2)w^{-(n+k)(p-1)-n-1}
$$
Now, this implies that $g_n=0$ $\forall n\geq2$, which isn't right. What did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It is a bit different, but how about [this expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.5%2Bx%5E5-x%2Cx%3Da%2Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5Ba%5E%28n*5%29%2C%7Ba%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%2Ca%3D0.5)? After 10 terms, the error is $0.00012…$

Comment: @TymaGaidash I need an exact expression.